# .net System.XML SelectSingleNode when child elements haven't got namespace

Tags: .net, xml, system.xml

So trying to select node "NumSerieFacturaEmisor" from this XML:

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns4:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas
            xmlns:ns4="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/igic/ws/RespuestaSuministro.xsd"
            xmlns="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/igic/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
            <ns4:RespuestaLinea>
                <ns4:IDFactura>
                    <IDEmisorFactura>
                        <NIF>B44444395</NIF>
                    </IDEmisorFactura>
                    <NumSerieFacturaEmisor>FV1810007</NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
                    <FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>24-10-2018</FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
                </ns4:IDFactura>
            </ns4:RespuestaLinea>
        </ns4:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Using DotNet System.Xml functions:

```
XMLNamespaceMgr.AddNamespace('ns4','https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/igic/ws/RespuestaSuministro.xsd');
FoundXMLNodeList = XMLRootNode.SelectNodes('//ns4:RespuestaLinea',XMLNamespaceMgr);
FOR Index := 0 TO FoundXMLNodeList.Count - 1 DO BEGIN
 XMLNode := FoundXMLNodeList.Item(Index);
 FoundXMLNode := XMLRootNode.SelectSingleNode('//ns4:IDFactura//NumSerieFacturaEmisor',XMLNamespaceMgr);
 DocNo := FoundXMLNode.InnerText;
END
```

So **XMLRootNode.SelectSingleNode returns null**. What I see is that the parent element has the "ns4" namespace, but the child doesn't have a namespace. Do I have to change my code in order to select the "NumSerieFacturaEmisor" child element?

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML instead? That tends to make working with namespaces much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, just needed to add a custom namespace for my child elements.

So the final code is:

```
XMLNamespaceMgr.AddNamespace('ns4','https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/igic/ws/RespuestaSuministro.xsd');
XMLNamespaceMgr.AddNamespace('custom','https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/igic/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd');
FoundXMLNodeList = XMLRootNode.SelectNodes('//ns4:RespuestaLinea',XMLNamespaceMgr);
FOR Index := 0 TO FoundXMLNodeList.Count - 1 DO BEGIN
 XMLNode := FoundXMLNodeList.Item(Index);
 FoundXMLNode := XMLRootNode.SelectSingleNode('//ns4:IDFactura//custom:NumSerieFacturaEmisor',XMLNamespaceMgr);
 DocNo := FoundXMLNode.InnerText;
END
```